# Avoid Materialize nav bar from collapsing

Tags: javascript, css, navbar, materialize, collapsable

Currently I am using `materialize navbar` and for the most part it work perfectly.

```
<div className="navbar-fixed fadeInDown animated">
    <nav>
        <div className="nav-wrapper">
            ...
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The thing is, it has an automatic collapsing behavior and for that reason I removed the `id="nav-mobile"`.

It still collapses I think because it gets the `width change events`.

How do I make it so that it just changes the width without collapsing eventually?

Comment: Can you post the whole contents of the navbar? This could be caused by inner elements not shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html), remove the `button-collapse` from your navbar and remove the initialization code: `$(".button-collapse").sideNav();`

Comment: I haven't added that line in my document ready so I can't remove it. The issue is that even though I have no set the sticky nav to be reactive it is.